# How to solve python syntax error for a simple click tool?

Tags: python, azure-devops, command-line-interface

I am working on creating a simple click tool for CLI. The code is shown thus:

```
import click

@click.command(help="This is just a hello app. It does nothing.")   #click menu setup and help show
@click.option("--name", prompt="I need your name", help="Need name")    #something that accepts the parameters as options then probbaly a help message
@click.option("--color", prompt="I need your color", help="This is your color") #color setup with a prompt for color request and help clause as well
def hello(name, color):
    if name == "Samuel":
        click.echo("Samuel, you are always DevOps blue.")
        click.echo(click.style(f"Hello {name}!", fg="blue"))
    else:
        else:
            click.echo(f"Your color is {color}!")
            click.echo(click.style(f"Hello {name}!", fg=color))

if __name__ == "__main__":      #only run this block if it runs as a script and it's close to having a CLI
    hello()
```

After running this command `python2 click.py`, the resulting error is shown thus:

```
File "click.py", line 9
    click.echo(click.style(f"Hello {name}!", fg="blue"))
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: What's with the repeated `else:` keywords?

Comment: Removed it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`python2 click.py` implies that you're running this with Python 2, but f-strings like `f"Hello {name}!"` are only available [since Python 3.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), so you should run this code with Python 3 instead.

To remain compatible with Python 2, use `str.format`:

```
"Hello {}!".format(name)
```

Comment: I was able to change the code base to python3 so I do not have to refactor but there is still an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "click.py", line 1, in <module>
    import click
  File "/home/samuel/Desktop/Azure-DevOps/click.py", line 3, in <module>
    @click.command(help="This is just a hello app. It does nothing.")   #click menu setup and help show
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'click' has no attribute 'command' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: @SamBayo, Python thinks that `import click` refers to `/home/samuel/.../click.py`, so it'll try to recursively import it _into itself_, which is a case of a "circular import". You should rename your file to something else.